# Connecting to Multiple Serial COM port using multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, serial-port

We have a research that requires a server (using sockets) to have com ports with cisco device connected to it. The problem is I can not initialize multiple threads.

Here is a code on how we initialize the Thread for a com port.

```
public CLI(String portName) {    
String driverName = "com.sun.comm.Win32Driver";
try{
    CommDriver commdriver = (CommDriver)Class.forName(driverName).newInstance( );
    commdriver.initialize();
}catch (Exception e2){}
portList = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifiers();

while (portList.hasMoreElements()) {

    portId = (CommPortIdentifier) portList.nextElement();
    if (portId.getPortType() == CommPortIdentifier.PORT_SERIAL) {
        if (portId.getName().equals(portName)) {
            try{
            System.out.println("Welcome to " + portId.getName() + "!!");

            serialPort = (SerialPort) portId.open("COM", 2000);
            inputStream = serialPort.getInputStream();
            outputStream = serialPort.getOutputStream();
            serialPort.addEventListener(this);
            serialPort.notifyOnDataAvailable(true);

            serialPort.setSerialPortParams(9600,
            SerialPort.DATABITS_8,
            SerialPort.STOPBITS_1,
            SerialPort.PARITY_NONE);
            serialPort.setFlowControlMode(1);
            }catch(Exception ex){}

            readThread = new Thread(this);
            readThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
}

 public void run() {
   }

public void send_msg(String line){
        try {
            outputStream.write((line + (char)13).getBytes());
            outputStream.flush();
        } catch (IOException e) {}

}

 public void serialEvent(SerialPortEvent event) {
    switch(event.getEventType()) {
    case SerialPortEvent.BI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OE:
    case SerialPortEvent.FE:
    case SerialPortEvent.PE:
    case SerialPortEvent.CD:
    case SerialPortEvent.CTS:
    case SerialPortEvent.DSR:
    case SerialPortEvent.RI:
    case SerialPortEvent.OUTPUT_BUFFER_EMPTY:
        break;
    case SerialPortEvent.DATA_AVAILABLE:

        byte[] readBuffer = new byte[8];
    try {
        inputStream.reset();
        outputStream.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
        try {
            while (inputStream.available() > 0) {
                int numBytes = inputStream.read(readBuffer);
            }
            Cleaner = new String(readBuffer);

            for(int ctr = 0; ctr < 8; ctr++)
                if((Cleaner.charAt(ctr) >= 32 && Cleaner.charAt(ctr) <= 127))
                {
                    receiver += Cleaner.charAt(ctr);
                    //System.out.print(Cleaner.charAt(ctr));
                }
                else if(Cleaner.charAt(ctr) == (char)13){
                    //test_prov.sendMessage(receiver);
                    test_prov.send_broadcast(receiver);
                    System.out.print(receiver);
                    receiver = "";
                }

        } catch (IOException e) {}
        break;
    }
}
```

The problem is when I initialize 2 of them it doesn't seem to read 1 of them.

Looking forward for a reply :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same `Runnable` for every thread. That runnable holds the IO streams used to communicate with one COM port. To handle multiple ports, you must have one set of specific IO streams per thread, ie. per `Runnable`.

The correct way to handle this is to split the logic handling the communication from the logic creating the threads.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not communicating on megabit speeds, multithreading is not necessary - just poll all ports in 10..100ms interval for incoming data.